# All requests through one function, which adds accessToken itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I don't want to repeat headers for all request.

```
async function fetchA() {
return await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: API_URL + `/api/a`,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)}
});
 }
async function fetchAById(id) {
return await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: API_URL + `/api/a/${id}`,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)}
});
 }
```

I assigned headers to const but in this case accessToken was null.

What is best way to create function which adds accessToken itself?

Comment: that's where you can use `axios.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = .... etc`

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121287/how-to-setup-axios-interceptors-with-react-context-properly) its called interceptor which is run on every axios call.

Comment: Thank you both! @FilipKováč the link you provided helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function getHeaders() {
       const serviceInstance = axios.create({
       url: API_URL + `/api/a`,
       headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)}
     });
     return serviceInstance;
  }

async function fetchA() {
   return await getHeaders().get(url)
   });
}
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you! i used this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121287/how-to-setup-axios-interceptors-with-react-context-properly]