# How to make functions exposed by useAuth hook available in plain JS files/modules

Tags: reactjs, axios

The auth logic is implemented and encapsulated in the AuthProvider and can be accessed using the useAuth() hook. We can invoke the useAuth() from either another hook or a functional component. But I need to access its two functions, namely getAccessToken and refreshAccessToken from a JS module named axios.ts that has nothing to with React. How can this be done?

```
// AuthProvider.ts
export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  //useState to set the local state in this component.
  login();
  logout();
  getAccessToken();            <------ get the access token from the local storage
  refreshAccessToken();
}
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

Note that refreshAccessToken() is setting the local state in the AuthProvider component and making a call to an api endpoint to refresh the token.

Based on the answer given in [this post](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2315), I created a separated module to register axios interceptors (instead of registering them in a React component) so that they are loaded only once.

axios-auth-refresh is a stable third-party module to intercept the requests and add authorization header to them and also makes calls to the refreshToken endpoint.

```
// axios.ts
import createAuthRefreshInterceptor from "axios-auth-refresh";

const axiosApiInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiEndipoint,
});

axiosApiInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  // Inject the token in request header
  if (getAccessToken()) {         <---- cannot access getAccessToken because React does not allow to 
use the hooks in plain JS files
    request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${getAccessToken()}`,
  }
  return request;
});

createAuthRefreshInterceptor(
  axiosApiInstance,
  refreshAccessToken,          <---- for the same reason, cannot obtain a reference 
to the refreshAccessToken defined in AuthProvider
  axiosAuthRefreshOptions
);
```

I need to access the getToken() and refreshAccessToken() in axios.ts to make it work. getToken() simply returns the token from the local storage and thus, as a workaround, I can access the local storage directly in the axios.ts.

But how to access refreshAccessToken, pl. guide.

Comment: I would create an other provider and put it as child of `AuthProvider` and provide the `axios` instance there. you can create a `useAxios` hook to access the axios instance.

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121287/how-to-setup-axios-interceptors-with-react-context-properly further justifies the approach that I am willing to take.

Comment: @karianpour I know about this. But there could be an issue according to this post.. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2315#issuecomment-547308574

Comment: Sure, that issue is obvious, the solution is to not render any thing in the `AxiosProvider` before that the `axios` instance is ready, and put the `axios` instance in useState. This way the `useAxios` hook will always have the correct `axios` instance.